# Cannot run the Start.java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, geoserver

I try to run the Start.java follwing [link] (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/quickstart/index.html#id6) the  with IntelliJ. 
but jetty facing an error .  

`06 Okt 17:53:18 WARN [webapp.WebInfConfiguration] - Web application not found src/main/webapp
06 Okt 17:53:18 WARN [webapp.WebAppContext] - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1bb5034{/geoserver,null,null}{src/main/webapp}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/webapp
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:493)`

I am working with master branch of 2.10-beta Geoserver. JDK and JRE is 1.8 Maven 3.0, IntelliJ Ultimate Edition . and all the dependencies are resolved.

Comment: does it work from the cli - cd geoserver_2.0.x/src/web/app
mvn jetty:run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @iant said , is better to use maven command which is  `cd geoserver_2.0.x/src/web/app mvn jetty:run .`

since maven do all the job. So I dont need to take care of it for each part in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your configuration defines some resources (and xml) in src/main/webapp but you haven't this folder